# wix - The Component element contains an unexpected child element 'Directory'

Tags: xml, vbscript, wix, installation, windows-installer

I am writing a VB script that recursively goes in to a directory and creates a WIX XML file
I am getting an error The Component element contains an unexpected child element 'Directory'. when i try to compile my WIX can someone help please.

```
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="simple.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
            <Directory Id="MSI" Name="MSI">
                <Component Id="first.txt" DiskId="1" Guid="*">
                    <File Id="first.txt" Name="first.txt" Source="C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\MSI\first.txt" />
                </Component>
                <Component Id="TestProduct" DiskId="1" Guid="*">
                    <Directory Id="TestProduct" Name="TestProduct">
                        <Component Id="snet" DiskId="1" Guid="*">
                            <Directory Id="snet" Name="snet">
                                <Component Id="file1.txt" DiskId="1" Guid="*">
                                    <File Id="file1.txt" Name="file1.txt" Source="C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\MSI\TestProduct\snet\file1.txt" />
                                </Component>
                                <Component Id="custom" DiskId="1" Guid="*">
                                    <Directory Id="custom" Name="custom">
                                        <Component Id="file2.txt" DiskId="1" Guid="*">
                                            <File Id="file2.txt" Name="file2.txt" Source="C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\MSI\TestProduct\snet\custom\file2.txt" />
                                        </Component>
                                    </Directory>
                                </Component>
                            </Directory>
                        </Component>
                    </Directory>
                </Component>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Feature Id="TestProductFeature" Title="Test" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="first.txt" />
        <ComponentRef Id="TestProduct" />
        <ComponentRef Id="snet" />
        <ComponentRef Id="file1.txt" />
        <ComponentRef Id="custom" />
        <ComponentRef Id="file2.txt" />
    </Feature>
    <UI />
</Product>
```

Comment: i removed part of the XML because its too long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WiX already has a program that does this, it's called [Heat](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/heat.html).  If you just want to write one yourself, you need to understand that a Directory can be a child of a Directory and
Directory is the parent of Component not the other way around.  A component can only install files in one directory.

You can use my tool [IsWiX](https://iswix.codeplex.com/) to drag and drop files and look at the resulting XML to get a feel for what it should look like.

Comment: " Directory can be a child of a Directory and Directory is the parent of Component"  
That is exactly what his code shows.  So what's the problem?  I am getting the same error

Comment: You cut out "not the other way around. A component can only install files in one directory".  This means Component cannot be a parent of Directory. https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/component.html